# Ядро Kernel.bin грузится и тут же идет на перезагрузку ПК

Tags: usb, grub, boot

Использую программу для загрузки с флэшки Grub4DOS
Отредактировал файл menu.lst и написал там только вот это:

```
title myKernel
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/kernel.bin
```

Дело в том что ядро грузится и тут же идёт на перезагрузку что делать не знаю помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Проверьте, не возникает ли после загрузки вашего ядра [прерывание *Double Fault*](https://dev64.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/interrupts-exceptions-reference/#interrupt-8). Для проверки поставьте в качестве обработчика этого прерывания вечный цикл с отключением прерываний (`test: cli // jmp test`). Если после этого перезагрузка прекращается, значит ваш обработчик прерываний сам провоцирует какое-то другое прерывание ошибкой времени выполнения, из-за чего возникает уже Triple Fault, отправляющий компьютер в перезагрузку.

Comment: Ф можно как то попроще а то я начинающий программист могу выложить Си файл

Comment: Так, похоже, я что-то не понял. Ядро ваше самописное или вы запускаете что-то стороннее?

Comment: Ну скажем так я учусь на этом ядре я его не писал

Comment: Раз вы решили связаться со внутренностями операционной системы, значит вам надо будет как минимум ознакомиться с тем, как работают и обрабатываются прерывания (события от железа). После этого вам надо будет найти обработчик прерывания #8 (того самого Double Fault) и заменить его на вечный цикл, описанный выше. Просто сходу невозможно понять (если нет .log-файлов, с чем надо обращаться к документации), перезагружается ли компьютер по желанию  ядра или из-за фатальной непредвиденной ошибки при его выполнении. Вот и предлагаю начать с проверки второй гипотезы.

Comment: https://jedipower999.wixsite.com/creative-os это мой сайт блог в посте Пишем рабочую ОС рассмотрены все файлы

Comment: А "Double Fault" это на языке Си или как это будет на ассемблере

Comment: кстати вечный цикл задан в Си файле в конце файла While(1)

Comment: посоветуйте хорошую книжку по написанию ОС

Comment: А если сделать так: написать pause то есть поставить паузу или с помощью goto например

Comment: Получилось и это правда в Kernel.c  я поработал с более старым ядром и оно не перезагружает компьютер потом в новых исходника в конце файла я просто изменил while(1) на return; и терминал вызвал такую ошибку при линковании: o kc.o
kc.o: In function `idt_init':
kernel.c:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/UNIX 2$ потому что в старом исходнике файл заканчивается return

Answer (score 0):

просто откатился назад в исходниках и действительно ошибка в kernel.c
А так всё работает, правда смущает мигающий курсор подчёркивание а так всё работает